# Middleware from NextAuth doesn't work in my NextJS 13 App Router App

Tags: next.js, next-auth, next.js13

I tried implementing the middleware functionality (https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/nextjs#middleware) in order to prevent unauthorised users to manually be able to hardcode their way to any page using the URL bar. However, this functionality doesn't work as of this moment.

I tried everything that I could think of to resolve the issue including:

1. Set up a SessionProvider for the whole app and wrapped all in the body tag of the root layout in it + app/api/auth/[...nextauth] route.ts as follows:

```
import NextAuth, { User } from "next-auth";
import { JWT } from "next-auth/jwt";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

const handler = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        email: { label: "Email", type: "email" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL}/auth/login/`, {
          method: "POST",
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            email: credentials?.email,
            password: credentials?.password,
          }),
        });

        const user = await res.json();

        // If the response object contains a "detail" property, it means that the login was unsuccessful according to api
        if (!user.detail) {
          const userWithTokens: User = {
            ...user,
            accessToken: user?.access,
            refreshToken: user?.refresh,
          };
          return userWithTokens;
        } else {
          throw new Error("Invalid credentials");
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  // Override default pages coming from Next Auth with our own
  pages: {
    signIn: "/auth/signin",
    signOut: "/auth/signin",
    error: "/auth/signin",
  },
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      // Initial sign in
      if (user) {
        token.accessToken = user.accessToken;
        token.refreshToken = user.refreshToken;

        return token;
      } else if (token?.refreshToken) {
        // Access token has expired, try to update it
        const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL}/auth/refresh/`, {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            refresh: token.refreshToken,
          }),
        });

        const newToken = await res.json();

        if (newToken.access) {
          token = {
            ...token,
            accessToken: newToken.access,
          };
        }
      }

      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      // Add property to session
      session.accessToken = token.accessToken as JWT;
      return session;
    },
  },
});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

```
2\.  Set up the env variables including NEXTAUTH*SECRET, NEXTAUTHURL = localhost:3000 (in dev), SECRET_KEY ,*

3\. middleware.ts file  on the same level as the app directory:
```

```
export { default } from "next-auth/middleware";

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    // Match all request paths except for /auth/*
    "/((?!auth).*)",
  ],
};
```

Comment: The issue was resolved when I removed the signOut's custom page which was pointing to /auth/singin. Idk why that worked but if someone could explain, that would be awesome.

Comment: I don't have a signOut custom page and It still does not trigger. I love the fact that I promote NextJs 13 as the best thing that ever happened while hating it so much.